# How to confirm IIS is using dotnet 6

Tags: .net-core, .net-6.0, iis-6

I have built and deployed a dotnet 6 `6.0.300` application under IIS. The application contains this `global.json` file:

```
    {
        "sdk": {
            "version": "6.0.300"
        }
    }
```

The IIS app pool is configured to use `No Managed Code` under the .NET CLR version.

There is a previous version of dotnet (`3.1.421`) installed.

If I run the `dotnet --version` command I see `3.1.425` and `dotnet --info` shows:

```
    .NET runtimes installed:
      Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.31 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
      Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.20 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
      Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.31 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.20 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.31 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

How can I confirm conclusively that the net6 version is being used to run the application?

Comment: Do you have the *.csproj file?

Comment: @JRichardsz since the post says _"I have built "_ - it is safe to assume that OP has the csproj file.

Comment: If you have a valid csproj, it is safe to assume that the required net version is in that file. So if you run it with another net version, an error will be thrown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--version` outputs the SDK version, not runtime. From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet#options-for-displaying-environment-information-and-available-commands):

> Prints out the version of the .NET SDK used by `dotnet` commands, which may be affected by a `global.json` file. Available only when the SDK is installed.

It has nothing to do with runtime selected for your app during runtime.

And you can be completely sure that older major runtime version will never be used because runtime selection does not support rolling backwards to the previous major version (for quite obvious reasons).

From the [.NET version selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection#framework-dependent-apps-roll-forward) doc:

> Framework-dependent apps roll-forward
> The host chooses the latest patch version installed on the machine. For example, if you specified `net5.0` in your project file, and `5.0.2` is the latest .NET runtime installed, the `5.0.2` runtime is used.

##### *The application contains this global.json file*

`global.json` determines SDK used to build the app, but required runtime is determined by the specified target framework (i.e. you can use .NET 7 SDK to build .NET 6 app).

But if you want to be really-really sure you can always check the version programmatically:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(Environment.Version);
Console.WriteLine(RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription);
```